# Best place to store background images

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My WP8 app support changing theme, just a background image. User could choose the prepared backgournd image or choose from their device, I prepared 10 images for users. Should I place images in a theme folder in the same project of my app or place them in a class libarary as embeded resources? Which place is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedded resource is preferable since OS is more optimized to read those rather than standalone files. But the difference in speed may be negligible, so I suggest you to try and see if it makes any difference to you, especially on a low end device like Nokia Lumia 520.